# Add element in sorted array with recursion?

Tags: php, recursion

Code below is used to add an element in sorted array without using recursion. How can I implement the same functionality using recursion?

```
function Add (&$array, $number) {

    $size = count($array);
    array_push($array, $number);
    for ($i = $size; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if ($array[$i] > $array[$i - 1]) { 
            break; 
        }
        $temp = $array[$i - 1];
        $array[$i - 1] = $array[$i];
        $array[$i] = $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal with this code?

Comment: To make it recursive you just call `Add()` again somewhere inside the function, and it's recursive.

Comment: See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421611/add-element-in-sorted-array-with-recursion)

Comment: i want to make a recursive function that return the array as result

Comment: it can be done without recursion ! is it a homework ?

Comment: it can , but i'm very bad with recursion :D

Comment: Question was vague. Improved the clarity of question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add ($array, $nbre) {
        if (count ($array) == 0) return array ($nbre);
        if ($nbre > $array[0])   return array_merge (array ($array[0]), add (array_slice ($array, 1), $nbre));
        else                     return array_merge (array ($nbre), $array);
    }
```